# How to convert Image to Byte Array in ImageMagick C++

Tags: c++, imagemagick, unreal-engine4

I want to convert Magick::Image to byte array or rawdata in C++. Is there any way??

It was possible to save the pdf as an image and then load the image, but I want to load the pdf's image from Unreal without saving the image.
So I want to load a pdf image using uint8 data in Unreal.

Comment: Provide reproducible code with your post so that others can pinpoint the error better and provide solutions, and please read the faq on how to ask good questions